# Save previous value in jQuery toggle method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where the user is able to select the type of job Ad and the locations that he wishes to advertise. The job Ad price changes depending the type of the job offer and the number of locations.

Everything is working, but there is one thing missing or not working, for example there is a checkbox with a `FULLPACK` value, where basically if the user selects it it receives a new price (discount), but when I toggles out case the user doesnt choose this option I need the price updates to the previous price number, but can´t figure out the best way.

My code:

```
var adType;
var totalprice = 0.0;
var location;
var countLocations =1;

//hide step 2 div
$('#step2').hide();
$('#totalprice').html(totalprice);
$('.adType').change(function () {
    //after select one show next step
    $('#step2').show('slow');
    adType = $(this).val();
    //var checked = $("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked').val();   
    console.log(adType);
    switch(adType) {
        case "platinum":
            totalprice = 250.00;
            $('#totalprice').html(totalprice*countLocations)
            break;
        case "gold":
             totalprice = 125.00;
             $('#totalprice').html(totalprice*countLocations)
            break;
        case "silver":
             totalprice = 50.00;
             $('#totalprice').html(totalprice*countLocations)
            break;        
        default:
            totalprice = 0.00;
            $('#totalprice').html(totalprice*countLocations)
    }
});

$('.location').change(function () {
    location = $(this).val();
    countLocations = $('[name="countrylocation[]"]:checked').length;
    $('#totalprice').html(totalprice*countLocations);
    console.log(countLocations);
    if (location == 'FULLPACK') {
        $( "#allPackage" ).toggle(function() {
             $('#totalprice').html("new Price!")
        });     
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="adType" name="adType" type="radio" value="platinum">
<input class="adType" name="adType" type="radio" value="gold">
<input class="adType" name="adType" type="radio" value="silver"> 

<div class="col-md-12" id="step2">
    <h3>Step 2</h3>
    <div id="allPackage">
        <label class="checkbox"><input checked class="location" name=
        "countrylocation[]" type="checkbox" value="UK"> UK
        (default)</label> <label class="checkbox"><input class="location"
        name="countrylocation[]" type="checkbox" value="SP"> Spain</label>
        <label class="checkbox"><input class="location" name=
        "countrylocation[]" type="checkbox" value="IT"> Italy</label>
    </div><label class="checkbox"><input class="location" name=
    "countrylocation[]" type="checkbox" value="FULLPACK"> Full Language
    Package</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <p>Price: <span id="totalprice"></span> EUR</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you also add the HTML part.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴛᴜʀғɪʟɪᴘɪᴀᴋ just added the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check whether the *"FULLPACK"* is actually `:checked`

Using `.toggle()` (as in your code):

```
$('.location').change(function () {
    location = $(this).val();
    countLocations = $('[name="countrylocation[]"]:checked').length;
    if (location == 'FULLPACK'){
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        return $( "#allPackage" ).toggle(function(){
             $('#totalprice').html(checked ? "new Price!" : (totalprice*countLocations));
        });
    }
    $('#totalprice').html(totalprice*countLocations);
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yzm7dw84/1/)</kbd>

---

Or using `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`:

```
$('.location').change(function () {
    location = $(this).val();
    countLocations = $('[name="countrylocation[]"]:checked').length;
    if (location == 'FULLPACK' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
        return $( "#allPackage" ).slideUp(function(){
             $('#totalprice').html("new Price!");
        });
    }else if (location == 'FULLPACK'){
        return $( "#allPackage" ).slideDown(function(){
            $('#totalprice').html(totalprice*countLocations);
        });
    }
    $('#totalprice').html(totalprice*countLocations);
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yzm7dw84/)</kbd>

Comment: You're welcome :-) Updated the code and added example with `.toggle()` method aswell

Comment: One last question Artur that i notice and i think could be a problem, the totalprice variable it doesnt keep changing it alwasy 50 because of the first option, and this could be a problem because limit for further calculations.

Comment: @MônicaR. Not really sure what you mean. When you change `adType` ? Something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/yzm7dw84/2/